# Generate random points on a surface of the cylinder

Tags: python

I want to generate random points on the surface of cylinder such that distance between the points fall in a range of 230  and 250. I used the following code to generate random points on surface of cylinder:

```
import random,math
H=300
R=20
s=random.random()
#theta = random.random()*2*math.pi
for i in range(0,300):
    theta = random.random()*2*math.pi
    z = random.random()*H
    r=math.sqrt(s)*R
    x=r*math.cos(theta)
    y=r*math.sin(theta)
    z=z
    print 'C'  , x,y,z
```

How can I generate random points  such that they fall with in the range(on the surfaceof cylinder)?

Comment: Distance along the surface of the cylinder, or straight-line (Euclidean)?

Comment: along surface of cylinder

Comment: Please add that to the question.

Comment: is the question clear ? I am have to generate some points such that the distance between any two points is between 230  and 250

Comment: I don't think the question is clear. You are saying that no two points can be closer to each other than 230, and that no two points can be further from each other than 260, right?  Doesn't that mean that the number of points would have to be fairly small, like, 3?

Comment: Or are you saying that you want to generate a series of pairs of points, where, for each pair, the one point in the pair is in the range (230,260) from other point?

Comment: I agree with @Robᵩ - with the given constraints the maximum number of points on the surface is three, and only if the first point is close to the base/top of the cylinder, elsewhere you can accomodate only two points.  @user1407199: why are you retrieving the square root of a random number in `r=math.sqrt(s)*R` ?

Comment: furthermore, with the given algorithm the points are inside a cylinder, not on its surface, since you are using a random radius `r` defined as `0 <= r <= R`

Comment: Sorry for not being clear,

Comment: Sorry for not being clear , I want to genrate some points on surface, where no two points are closer than 230 units of distance.

Comment: Can the points also be on the top or bottom of the cylinder?

Comment: yes they can be the only constraint is distance between them

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is a [Poisson disc sampling](http://devmag.org.za/2009/05/03/poisson-disk-sampling/)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete solution, but an insight that should help. If you "unroll" the surface of the cylinder into a rectangle of width `w=2*pi*r` and height `h`, the task of finding distance between points is simplified. You have not explained how to measure "distance along the surface" between points on the top of the cylinder and the side- this is a slightly tricky bit of geometry.

As for computing the distance along the surface when we created an artificial "seam", just use both (x1-x2) and (w -x1+x2) - whichever gives the shorter distance is the one you want.

I do think that @VincentNivoliers' suggestion to use Poisson disk sampling is very good, but with the constraints of h=300 and r=20 you will get terrible results no matter what.

Answer (score 1):

The basic way of creating a set of random points with constraints in the positions between them, is to have a function that modulates the probability of points being placed at a certain location. this function starts out being a constant, and whenever a point is placed, forbidden areas surrounding the point are set to zero. That is difficult to do with continuous variables, but reasonably easy if you discretize your problem.

The other thing to be careful about is the being on a cylinder part. It may be easier to think of it as random points on a rectangular area that repeats periodically. This can be handled in two different ways:

1. the simplest is to take into consideration not only the rectangular tile where you are placing the points, but also its neighbouring ones. Whenever you place a point in your main tile, you also place one in the neighboring ones and compute their effect on the probability function inside your tile.
2. A more sophisticated approach considers the probability function then convolution of a kernel that encodes forbidden areas, with a sum of delta functions, corresponding to the points already placed. If this is computed using FFTs, the periodicity is anatural by product.

The first approach can be coded as follows:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np

r, h = 20, 300
w = 2*np.pi*r
int_w = int(np.rint(w))
mult = 10
pdf = np.ones((h*mult, int_w*mult), np.bool)
points = []
min_d, max_d = 230, 250

available_locs = pdf.sum()
while available_locs:
    new_idx = np.random.randint(available_locs)
    new_idx = np.nonzero(pdf.ravel())[0][new_idx]
    new_point = np.array(np.unravel_index(new_idx, pdf.shape))
    points += [new_point]
    min_mask = np.ones_like(pdf)
    if max_d is not None:
        max_mask = np.zeros_like(pdf)
    else:
        max_mask = True
    for p in [new_point - [0, int_w*mult], new_point +[0, int_w*mult],
              new_point]:
        rows = ((np.arange(pdf.shape[0]) - p[0]) / mult)**2
        cols = ((np.arange(pdf.shape[1]) - p[1]) * 2*np.pi*r/int_w/mult)**2
        dist2 = rows[:, None] + cols[None, :]
        min_mask &= dist2 > min_d*min_d
        if max_d is not None:
            max_mask |= dist2 < max_d*max_d
    pdf &= min_mask & max_mask
    available_locs = pdf.sum()
points = np.array(points) / [mult, mult*int_w/(2*np.pi*r)]
```

If you run it with your values, the output is usually just one or two points, as the large minimum distance forbids all others. but if you run it with more reasonable values, e.g.

```
min_d, max_d = 50, 200
```

Here's how the probability function looks after placing each of the first 5 points:
[image]

Note that the points are returned as pairs of coordinates, the first being the height, the second the distance along the cylinder's circumference.